# Fade in Fade out button menu

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I want to make a 'menu' with 4 options. This has to be 1 big frame where the buttons are being faded in and faded out over time, 1 by 1.
So only 1 button is visible at any given time , not 4;

These buttons ofcourse are filled with Images

I don't know how to start , i've checked out some photoalbum code but it hasn't helped me.

The main problem is the user can click at any time in the animation of fade in and fade out, so how to decide when to go where ?
Because when one imagebutton is faded out 50% another is 50% faded in.

Comment: Please provide code and rephrase you question. I don't know what your problem is. To you want to start the second fade after the fist fade is finished? To you want that the user can click during fades?

Comment: i havn't actually started coding that part since i don't have the designs ( they'll be ready tonight) . I'm just asking for some ideas since i'm not good with animations.  And yes the user has to be able to click the button while it fades

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this....

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:self.view];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
[yourButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:your-image-name] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 0):

if you dont want that the user can click during an animation then just [disable](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIControl/enabled) (UIControl is inherited by UIButton) the buttons during animation.

You can set the UIView-Animation-Delegate to your class so your class gets notified when animation starts, ends, ...

[[UIView setAnimationDelegate]](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/setAnimationDelegate%3a)

**edit:** if you want that the user can click on buttons during animation you have to know the wanted behaviour: which buttons should be clickable at which time?